# make the textview align vertically on the left side of the screen

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a listview that will be having a textview (used as a label) to fit the left side of the screen in a vertical way that will take the size of the row of the listview. check the image.[image]

This is easily implemented in iOS.
I want to have the Phonecall1 and Phonecall2 mimiced.

Many solutions on stackoverflow suggest creating a custom class and so forth.

Is there any simple way for this ?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weather"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:text="something" />
```

Comment: Set the height. It will work fine

Comment: set height to what ? there are millions of devices and each height for a row can be way too different

Answer (score 1):

For API 11 and above , In your text view Use  android:rotation and set height

Comment: it is not being aligned totally right, the center of rotation is wrong... and its being placed somewhere weird in the layout